# SQL Query - Joining, Adding and Lowest

Tags: sql, vb.net

Not quite sure how to attack this so I'm putting the question out there, i can do normal select statements and group but this seems a little out of my realm. Joining all the Same Product ID on the same date, adding the total times, selecting the lowest best time, adding all the cycle counts, waiting for operator and production times.

My select statement is as so:

```
sql = "SELECT Product_ID, Date_Time, ulTotBoardCycleTime, ulBestBoardCycleTime, ulBoardCycleCount, ulWaitingForOperator, ulProductionTime FROM [i_import_general_timers] WHERE DATE_TIME >= @startdata2 AND DATE_TIME < @enddata2 AND ulBoardCycleCount > 0 ORDER BY Product_ID DESC"
```

[image: What im trying to achieve]

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: I think I understand everything else but the lowest part, why do you have value 555 in the example, should that not be 137? Also this is pure sql-question, not VB.Net

Comment: My bad, meant to be 137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the proper aggregation functions with a group by.

```
SELECT Product_ID, Date_Time, sum(ulTotBoardCycleTime) as TotalTime, min(ulBestBoardCycleTime) as BestTime, sum(ulBoardCycleCount) as CycleCount, sum(ulWaitingForOperator) as WaitingFor, sum(ulProductionTime) as ProductionTime
    FROM [i_import_general_timers] 
    WHERE DATE_TIME >= @startdata2 AND DATE_TIME < @enddata2 AND ulBoardCycleCount > 0 
    GROUP by Product_ID, Date_Time
    ORDER BY Product_ID DESC
```

Comment: Good answer, though needs a bit more if he wants only the date-part grouped, not by time.

Comment: Understood but in op's select statement the column is addressed as Date_Time

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the example result (lower part of the image), he has only the date.

Comment: Hi Chaps thanks for the code - i used "DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Date_Time),0)" within the select and the group and it seemed to work